# Need to change field name in account form in odoo 11

Tags: odoo

I need to change a field name in Odoo 11 installed on Windows.

In the customer credit notes field name (Taxes), I need to change that to (Pat).

**How can I change it? Is it possible to change in XML through overriding and is it the correct way?**

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do this through the xml using either one of below method.

```xml
<xpath expr="//field[@name='your_field_name']" position="attributes">
      <attribute name="string">Pat</attribute>
</xpath>
```

**OR**

```xml
 <field name="your_field_name" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="string">Pat</attribute>
 </field>
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in XML if you want to do it only in that view. If you want to do it for all views, add string option in your Python code:

tax_ids = fields.Many2many('taxes.taxes',string = 'Pat' )

So in your dB and code references it will be called tax_ids but the user will see 'Pat'